# turning an .animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow"); function into a toggel left - right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, toggle

im having a little trouble figuring out how to turn a .animate left function into a toggeled animate function, ie click once animate left, click again animate right.

the jquery im using at the moment is

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $("#img-slider").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

ive tried changing .animate to .toggle, but it dosnt seem to work and im not sure why, any helps much appreciated !

Comment: You can use `data()` to save the status, and then do whatever based on that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var goRight = true;
$("#right").click(function () {
    $("#img-slider").animate({left: goRight ? "+=50px" : "-=50px"}, "slow");
    goRight = !goRight;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A `.toggle` could replace the `.click`, not the `.animate`. That gets a bit verbose, though.

```
$("#right").toggle(function () {
  $("#img-slider").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
}, function () {
  $("#img-slider").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Also, be careful of what happens when `#right` is clicked while the animation is running; depending on the desired behavior, a [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) might be needed.

Comment: You still need the click to call `toggle()` ... :)

Comment: No: "Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks." http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/